# Why rspec has one day difference sometime in rails 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

In rspec, we would like to check if a date field has been updated by the update in invoice controller. Here is the code:

```
it "should have corp head id and approve date" do
  cust = Factory(:customer)
  u = Factory(:user)
  rfq = Factory(:rfq, :sales_id => u.id, :customer_id => cust.id, :sales_id => u.id)
  q = Factory(:quote, :rfq_id => rfq.id) 
  i = Factory(:invoice, :quote_id => q.id, :approved_by_corp_head => nil )       
  session[:corp_head] = true
  session[:user_id] = u.id     
  get 'update', :id => i.id, :quote_id => q.id, :invoice => {:paid_out => true, :approved_by_corp_head => true}
  i.reload.corp_head_id.should == u.id
  i.reload.approve_date_corp_head.strftime("%Y/%m/%d").should == Time.now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
end
```

In invoice controller, there is a line to record the Time.now:

```
    invoice.approve_date_corp_head = Time.now
```

It is odd that sometimes line `i.reload.approve_date_corp_head.strftime("%Y/%m/%d").should == Time.now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")` will fail saying that there is one day difference between dates compared. It seems that the line would fail when we run rspec late at the night (before 12am though). We haven't seen failure early in the morning.

Anyone has idea about this odd behavior? Thanks so much.

Comment: which time zone are you from?

Comment: It is because of the Time difference in the zones please use the `offset` along with `Time.now` to make the `Time.now` get the time from your time zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would recommend that you ensure that all times that you are testing against are in UTC. That way it stops any timezone differences, especially if you are in a timezone further from GMT and it is either morning or evening.

Second, I'd recommend using [TimeCop](https://github.com/jtrupiano/timecop) to stop time, thus if you put a sleep in just before the .should step, it would still give the correct answer if you run over the unit of time.

Answer (score 3):

Change the expectation in the spec to

```
i.reload.approve_date_corp_head.strftime("%Y/%m/%d").should == Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

I would also echo Shaun's recommendation to use TimeCop

Comment: Even with time traveling, one should be testing date and times in UTC to better emulate the hosting environment.